# how to get barchart for chart.js to be a baseline of -80

Tags: javascript, charts

I am using chart.js and am trying to create a barchart where most of the points are negative numbers.  I want the baseline to be -80. Is this possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasnt able to.  Instead I had to create my own labels that corresponded with 0 = -80 and so on.